# display related entity in Dynamics 365 and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I created entity with 3 fields:

- text field
- number field
- relation to Account

I created the JS code to display or edit those fields, but is there a way to display data from Account entity using formContext from my actual entity?

```
function test(executionContext) {
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();    

    //text
    var text = formContext.data.entity.attributes.getByName('new_text').getValue();
    text.setValue("new text");

    //number
    var number = formContext.data.entity.attributes.getByName('new_number').getValue();
    number.setValue(5);

    //id field for another entity
    var number = formContext.data.entity.attributes.getByName('new_accountid').getValue();

    //my ideal solution would've look like this, but it doesn't working
    number.getParent().attributes.getByName('account_name').getValue();

}
```

Comment: number variable is used twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relation to Account is a lookup field. [How to get/set the lookup attribute value?](http://www.mscrmconsultant.com/2012/08/get-and-set-lookup-value-using.html)

You can get it’s value by:

```
var lookup = new Array();
lookup = formContext.getAttribute("Lookup Field Name").getValue();
if (lookup != null) {
    var name = lookup[0].name;
    var id = lookup[0].id;
    var entityType = lookup[0].entityType;
}
```

You can set its value by:

```
formContext.getAttribute("Lookup Field Name").setValue([{ id: recordid, name: recordname, entityType: entityname}]);
```

If you just want to display some other attribute from that lookup record in current entity form, you can use **Quick view form** of that lookup entity in current entity.

If you want to retrieve a different attribute from Account lookup record & set it to a current entity form field, then use `Xrm.Webapi` to fetch it & set the value.

Comment: Seems like Xrm.Webapi did the job. Thanks.